# Inconsistencies with calculating mean brightness per pixel of different images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, imagej

My code gets an image and calculates its mean brightness and standard deviation. When I run the code on a certain data set .TIF which is generally pretty dark and compare the values I get from running the code to the histogram in imageJ which I trust as a reliable source I get the same value. When I run it on a new data set .tiff and compare the values the brightness is very different, but the standard deviation is the same.

I attached a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F0jjtJODefvXQDIwxaPX3AzlEwlvkTkj?usp=sharing) to a google drive folder with the 2 images from each sample along with their values side by side (white background is ImageJ).

This is my how I calculate the mean brightness and std:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def calc_xray_count(image_path):
    original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    median_filtered_image = cv2.medianBlur(original_image, 5)
    median_filtered_image += 1  # Avoid not counting black pixels in image
    pixel_count = np.prod(median_filtered_image.shape)
    img_brightness_sum = np.sum(median_filtered_image)
    img_var = np.var(median_filtered_image)
 
    if (pixel_count > 0):
        img_avg_brightness = (img_brightness_sum/pixel_count) -1 # Subtract back to real data
    else:
        img_avg_brightness = 0
 
    print(f"mean brightness: {img_avg_brightness}")
    print(f"mean std: {np.sqrt(img_var)}")
    return img_avg_brightness, img_var
```

Please note that I apply a median filter here. In the comparison I saved the image already with the applied median filter. The original images differ by DPI (72 vs 96), but after I apply the median filter they're both 96 DPI. Nevertheless, both images are 16 bit.

Since I want to count the black pixels in the image I temporary add +1 to the pixels of the image just to subtract them back.

I tried using different libraries instead of cv2, but the issue still persists.

I would kindly appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Comment: the standard deviation might be the same as it represents the contrast from a given average brightness.

Comment: Your two data sets are quite different. Working is very dark. But non-working is very bright.  The means of the two cannot be the same. If you find they are similar, then one tool or the other is scaling the data range automatically so that it is visible.  Exactly what values are you trying to compare.  The average values for the two images should not be the same.

Comment: I'm just trying to verify that my mean brightness for picture is true meaning it aligns with what the ImageJ program tells me. The "true" image is one I got beforehand and the "non-true" image is an image I took myself. When I tried taking a very dark image myself it still differed from that of ImageJ. This leads me to believe that there might be something wrong with my pictures I feed into the program since the other images I have which weren't taken by me seem to work. Still, I'm trying to wrap my head around this since both images are images.

Comment: Your camera may be outputting auto-brightness-contrast adjusted images. Check if there is a raw mode for the output.

Answer (score 0):

After testing with my own images shot at 8 bit, the results were good. This meant that the problem is reading the 16 bit image.

To make sure the image is properly read I did the following change to 'original_image':

```py
original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this wasn't the final fix. The thing that helped was rewriting `calc_xray_count()` to:

```
    def calc_xray_count(self, image_path):
        original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
        median_filtered_image = cv2.medianBlur(original_image, 5)
        img_mean_count = median_filtered_image.mean()

        return img_mean_count
```